# TEXT function returning different values in two different spreadsheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am confused about the following:

- On spreadsheet A, `=TEXT(41432, "mm/dd/yyyy")` returns 06/07/2013
- On spreadsheet B, `=TEXT(41432, "mm/dd/yyyy")` returns 06/08/2017

all on the same computer! What's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the options on the file: 
File \ Options \ Advanced \ Scroll down to When Calculating this workbook and you'll see that one of the workbooks has the Use 1904 date system activated.

The 1904 is used by default on Macs, not on PCs

Check out [this microsoft kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180162) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to change this setting without having it move all the dates in the sheet back by 4 years?

Comment: I guess this answers my question... so annyoing. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180162

Answer (score 1):

To update the dates in your file, you can use this macro. It will be faster than a manual update.

```
Sub UpdateDates()
Dim sht As Worksheet, rg As range

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each rg In sht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumber).Cells
        If IsDate(rg) Then rg = rg - 1462 'adjust + / - 1462 depending on your needs
    Next rg
Next sht

With application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```